# Chrome app get "Set-Cookie" header

Tags: ajax, cookies, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-app

I'm building a Chrome app and want to be able to login using the app.
How can I enable the `Set-Cookie` header use for an ajax call inside the Chrome app?

```
 console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()); // Returns not set-cookie
 console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie')); // Returns null
```

Comment: To be able to do auth, if you control the server-side part, you should implement another auth protocol, say, OAuth.

Comment: Then, sadly, the answer is "xhr + cookies + app is not something really supported at all"

Comment: @Xan, So auth with `set-cookie` isn't in anyway possible?

Comment: The cookie will be set and used if you send `withCredentials` requests; but you cannot read it from your app, and you can't clear it either. It's a mess.

Comment: @Xan, that was the answer that I needed. Thanks!!